# How can I get the anglo saxon accounting module in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I installed odoo 8 and its accounting module. When I installed the accounting and finance, it didn't ask me what I want, it just installed the app. I just uninstall and install the accounting and finance app, and still the same thing happen.

How can I get the anglo saxon accounting module?

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator, go to Settings, and click on "Apps" under the "Modules" heading. In the search bar (on the upper right) click the x beside "Featured" so your search includes other modules. Then search for

```
account_anglo_saxon
```

This should show the module with an install button.

Answer (score 0):

inherit `view_company_form` view and and `anglo_saxon_accounting` field

```
    <record id="view_company_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.company.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.company</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='rml_header1']" position="after">
                <separator string=""/>
                <group >
                   <field name="anglo_saxon_accounting" />
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```